# Get the SUM() from another table and apply it in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

How to get the sum of `Qty * Price` in `#OrderDetail` in to the `TotalCost` column in `#Order`.

> Order

```
ID   |   TotalCost
1    |    100
```

> OrderDetail

```
OrderID   |   BasePrice   |   QtyOrdered
1         |    100.00     |      1
1         |     50.00     |      3
```

I tried the below query, but it gives me the above result.

```
UPDATE #Order
SET #Order.TotalCost = #OrderDetails.QtyOrdered * #OrderDetails.BasePrice
FROM #OrderDetails,#Order
WHERE #OrderDetails.OrderID = #Order.ID
```

Result should be (100*1) + (50*3) = 250

Is it possible to achieve this without using INNER QUERY or TABLE VARIABLES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subquery` :

```
UPDATE o 
     SET o.TotalCost = (SELECT SUM(od.BasePrice * od.QtyOrdered) 
                        FROM #OrderDetails od 
                        WHERE od.OrderID = o.ID)
FROM #Order o;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to aggregate before joining:

```
UPDATE o
    SET TotalCost = od.cost
FROM o JOIN
     (SELECT od.OrderID, SUM(od.QtyOrdered * od.BasePrice) as cost
      FROM #OrderDetails od
      GROUP BY od.OrderID
     ) od
     ON od.OrderID = o.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT OrderID ,SUM(baseprice * QtyOrdered) as totalPrice
    FROM #OrderDetails
    GROUP BY OrderID 
)
UPDATE o
SET o.TotalCost = CTE.TotalPrice
FROM #Order INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.OrderID = o.ID
```